# how to transform data in input json string that contains arrays of json objects

Tags: arrays, json, spark-structured-streaming

first time posting, learning spark coding with Scala :

I have an input json string that contains arrays of json strings. For example
{
"proofOfDelivery": {
"POD_TYPE_CD": "P",
"LD_REFS": [
{
"REF_NBR": "14272260",
"REF_DSC": "Description111"
},
{
"REF_NBR": "34234371",
"REF_DSC": ""
},
{
"REF_NBR": "1 - Initial Pickup",
"REF_DSC": "Stop Order "
}
]
}
}
I want to replace all occurrences of empty string with null. So in the above there is one occurrence of empty string and it should be replaced by null. I know how to do it with "normal" columns, like POD_TYPE_CD above, but how can it be done for fields inside the array ? To summarize, I don't want to change any values, basically my input will become the output, BUT all empty strings need to be null (so in the above, it would be "REF_DSC":null )

Any suggestions or guidance would be great!

I tried using explode, i tried a map but none of them works and i dont have a good picture yet of how it works. I described above what i would expect the output to look like.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

by combining other posts from people i was able to figure it out:
First by using this commend i was able to get a json string out of the input :
.withColumn("LD_REFS", (get_json_object(to_json(col("record.proofOfDelivery")), "$.LD_REFS")).cast("string"))

then by using the following i was able to first replace all empty strings with null and then turn it back into a structured array (so that the output looks the same as the input except that instead of empty strings there are nulls)

val updatedDF=inputDF
.withColumn("LD_REFS", regexp_replace(col("LD_REFS"),"""","null"))
.withColumn("LD_REFS", from_json(col("LD_REFS"), ArrayType(new StructType().add("REF_DSC",StringType).add("REF_NBR",StringType))))

my output looks like this
"LD_REFS": [
{
"REF_DSC": null,
"REF_NBR": "14272260"
},
{
"REF_DSC": null,
"REF_NBR": "34234371"
},
{
"REF_DSC": "Stop Order ",
"REF_NBR": "1 - Initial Pickup"
},
{
"REF_DSC": "Intermodal Group (Old) Id",
"REF_NBR": "3114762"
}
]